# Should you make tests for constants?

Tags: perl, testing

I'd like to know if there is any value in providing a test to say that a constant equals x in my test suite.

A couple of benefits I see to doing it:

- You know when this value has changed, because the developer changing it will get a *failed* test
- If the developer updating the constant updates the test with the new value, the test will confirm that it was properly updated

Would that be beneficial or just a nuisance?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by a "constant". Certainly there is no point in testing whether `2 == 2`. I think you should post an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho, there is no benefit in it.

- if dev see failed tests because of a constant then he will simply update the same value in tests. so it's not a benefit, it's a duplication
- you should have tests for the code that uses the constant. if not unit tests then integration tests (e.g. address of the mail server) those tests should fail if something is wrong with the constant

the only tests for constant i can imagine is when your constant is some complex object then maybe you can tests if all required constraints between its properties are met. but if it's just, let's say, a number or string then, imho, it's just a waste of time because test maintenance costs and it gives you absolutely no additional security

Comment: Your second point is a good enough reason, I failed to think of that (am new to testing). Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your post. Please confirm that I have written it correctly

Comment: What do you make of the two circumstances in the OP's post where tests could be useful?

Comment: @Borodin Both of the OP's examples are covered by having tests for the code which uses the constant.  For example, testing that the domain name of the upload server is "blah.example.com" isn't as useful as testing that uploads are successfully received and processed.  Or maybe it's a tax rate, it's better to test that the tax calculations come out correct.  In addition, things like that should really be configuration values and not hard coded constants, further illustrating that testing their value is counter-productive.

Comment: @Bordin - you deleted some parts (e.g. mail server) so i rollbacked

Comment: @Schwern - you are absolutely right that it should be configuration. but from the code's point of view it's a constant so i still vote for doing the 'upload test' or 'tax calculation test'

Comment: I see more value in testing that a constant has been defined with a value, or even with a reasonable value, than testing whether it has a specific value.  If reasonable is an integer between 0 and 255, for example, test that it has been defined in that range.  In the user's specific case, one could test that it's been defined with a reasonable domain name or IP.

Comment: @DavidO i would use this only if i weren't able to check if code that uses the constant woks correctly. sticking with tax calculation: if it works then why do i need 'range tests'? it's just a duplicated and less specific test

Comment: @piotrek: The post is yours, and it is up to you what it says. But I am surprised that you think the phrase `e.g. address of the mail server` is so important that it is worth returning to the original version with terrible English. Most people will ignore you if you write like that.